# Doing a GROUP_CONCAT on a GROUP BY in MYSQL decreases the number of returned groups

Tags: mysql

When I do a GROUP BY on a field having an email text content,  MYSQL returns me the correct results:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM email_template et 
group by et.message;
```

It returns me in this case the valid values:

```
| # | count(*) |
----------------
| 1 |        1 |
| 2 |        1 |
| 3 |        1 |
| 4 |        1 |
| 5 |        1 |
| 6 |        1 |
| 7 |       59 |
----------------
```

However when I add a GROUP_CONCAT, it has effect on the returned results, which I did not expect.

```
SELECT count(*), GROUP_CONCAT(et.id SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM email_template et 
group by et.message;
```

It returns me in this case these invalid values (groups the first 6 results of previous query together):

```
| # | count(*) | GROUP_CONCAT                   |
-------------------------------------------------
| 1 |        6 |  21, 38, 28, 227, 233, 239     |
| 2 |       59 |  308, 311, 314, ...            |
-------------------------------------------------
```

A workaround is to MD5 hash the string, which yields correct results, but I do not understand why the second query does not work:

```
SELECT count(*), GROUP_CONCAT(et.id SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM email_template et 
group by MD5(et.message);
```

Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: `group by et.message` should give you _one_ record per message in the result set, period.  If you're not seeing consistent behavior there, then it implies that your underlying data is changing.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen interestingly it is not changing. when I rerun the first query or the md5 hack it still gives me the same good result.

Comment: note that it is running on mysql in google cloud

Comment: This seems very strange and unlikely.  What mysql version?  And show your actual data and table structure.

Comment: What is the datatype of your `message` column? Some versions of 5.7. had bugs when doing aggregate operations on `text`-columns. The effect was different, and I don't recall that `group_concat` had a problem, but it could actually be a bug (as your result should not be possible). It would also help a lot if you could create a sample (e.g. try to get it to fail with obfuscated data and maybe 4-5 rows, then post 4-5 inserts statements and the create table), and your MySQL version.